# SFML 2.1 and Codeblocks Error: sfml-graphics-2.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: c++, sfml

I've just begun to use c++ and SFML, and everything FINALLY ran fine. Before I would get Undefined Reference Errors, but I realized that I had been downloading the wrong type of SFML, getting SJLJ instead of DW2. The problem was fixed, but was replaced with another; now whenever I run an SFML program, it opens a small windows:

It says:

> The program can't start because sfml-graphics-2.dll is missing from
>   your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

And then when you press "Ok" or closed the window, the program would stop working. NOT TO BE CONFUSED: the program never opened, on the console did.

Here is the Code (probably useless) directly copied and pasted from the codeblocks tutorial site:

```js
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SFML is dynamically linked by default, which means that you need to place sfml-graphics-2.dll (along with the dll files of any other SFML subsystems you use) inside the same directory as your executable.

Comment: I know this is an old post but I have all this done. The app runs in the IDE but when double clicking on the EXE I get the error `_ZSt4_throw_out_of_range_fmtPKcz could not be located in sfml-graphics-2.dll`. All DLLs are in the same folder as my EXE

Answer (score 12):

Copy all  `dll`  files from main `SFML > bin` directory and paste them into your project folder. In my case it is `C:\Users\myname\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\SFML\SFML`
[image]

and if you want to run just the `exe` file. Place all `dll` files the same directory as the main `exe` file.

Answer (score 1):

Best option is Copy All the .dll files from  **SFML-2.4.2 > bin**. And past them to **C: > Windows > System32** folder. That's all you need to do.
Then Run your Program.
you will be able to run it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My error was when I was linking the libraries in the Compiler setting I had forgot to add the suffix "-s-d". This ending allows the compiler and debugger to function properly.