# missing sfml-graphics-d-2.dll when using SFML

Tags: c++, dll, graphics, codeblocks, sfml

I am coding in C++, using the SFML, since a little bit of time and everything has been running fine.
This morning I've been using the type sf::Image and some functions on that type, such as getPixel.
Then, the compilation works fine, however, when I try to run it, I get the missing dll error on sfml-graphics-d-2.dll.

I looked in the folder and I could see that indeed, there was no such dll! There was his brother sfml-graphics-2.dll instead however.
Why is it asking for the dll that I don't have :( ?

Informations:
I use code::blocks.
Linkers seems to be ok :
"C:\Program Files (x86)\SFML-2.3\lib\libsfml-graphics-d.a" for the debug
"C:\Program Files (x86)\SFML-2.3\lib\libsfml-graphics.a" for the release
I use the SFML2.
I'm on Windows 8.
My compiler is GCC MinGW.
I can't find sfml-graphics-d-2.dll on my computer (because I had to compile the SFML using Cmake, and it only generates files like sfml-graphics-2.dll, not like sfml-graphics-d-2.dll)

Thank you very much if you can help! :-)

Comment: Select Build Target All Or Resale That Surely Works,

Comment: I answered that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242013/sfml-2-1-and-codeblocks-error-sfml-graphics-2-dll-is-missing-from-your-computer/44126418#44126418 . That might help.

Answer (score 1):

The `-d` in `sfml-graphics-d-2.dll` stands for debug, so when you are building SFML, you need to change the build target from Release to Debug.

[image: code::blocks build target: Release]

The Debug build target should have been generated by CMake when you ran it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I was wrong, I was using the build target debug, not release. A whole day of active researches on Google has made me understand that.

I have recompiled the SFML using cmake, and I have put the generated missing dll in my folder. Now it is better! It isn't looking for missing dll anymore!

However, I have a pop-up window telling me that the entry point for the procedure _ZSt24__throw_out_of_range_fmtPKcz is missing in the sfml-system-d-2.dll file :(

How can I solve the problem?